# Efficient way to replace column of lists by matches with another data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like:

```
col11     col12
  X      ['A']
  Y      ['A', 'B', 'C']
  Z      ['C', 'A']
```

And another one that looks like:

```
 col21   col22
  'A'   'alpha'
  'B'   'beta'
  'C'   'gamma'
```

I would like to replace `col12` base on `col22` in a efficient way and get, as a result:

```
col31     col32
  X      ['alpha']
  Y      ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
  Z      ['gamma', 'alpha']
```

Comment: Are you looking to add two new columns: Col31 and Col32 or are you looking to replace the existing column: Col12

Comment: col31 and col11 are the same. Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use an indexed series as a mapper with a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
                    'col2': [['A'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'A']]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col21': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    'col22': ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']})

s = df2.set_index('col21')['col22']

df1['col2'] = [list(map(s.get, i)) for i in df1['col2']]
```

Result:

```
  col1                  col2
0    X               [alpha]
1    Y  [alpha, beta, gamma]
2    Z        [gamma, alpha]
```

Comment: Nice solution, super!

Comment: @jezrael, It won't be as efficient as a merge-based solution, but I can't figure out how you'd do it..

Comment: nested lists is possible convert, map and convert back, but in my opionion it should be slowier as pure list comprehension. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure its the most efficient way but you can turn your `DataFrame` to a `dict` and then use `apply` to map the keys to the values:

Assuming your first `DataFrame` is `df1` and the second is `df2`:

```
df_dict = dict(zip(df2['col21'], df2['col22']))
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"31":df1['col11'], "32": df1['col12'].apply(lambda x: [df_dict[y] for y in x])})
```

or as @jezrael suggested with nested list comprehension:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"31":df1['col11'], "32": [[df_dict[y] for y in x] for x in df1['col12']]})
```

note: `df3` has a default index

```
  31                    32
0  X               [alpha]
1  Y  [alpha, beta, gamma]
2  Z        [gamma, alpha]
```

Comment: @jezrael I'll check it out. Thanks!